# Which functions are equalizers in $\mathbf{Set}$?

Tags: category-theory

Goldblatt's "Topoi" shows that in $\mathbf{Set}$ all monic arrows are equalizers, using the following argument:

Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ be injective, let $C = \{ 0, 1 \}$ and define functions $g, h : B \rightarrow C$ as $g(b) = 1$ (so a constant function) and $h(b) = I[b \in \text{im} f]$, where $I$ is the indicator function. Then it's obvious that $g \circ f = h \circ f$.

But I'm not sure I intuitively accept it.

1. How do we use injectivity of $f$?
2. Shouldn't we require that $f$ is *non*-surjective? Otherwise $g = h$, and $f$ equalizes them "trivially". And we don't call an arrow an equalizer because it equalizes some other arrow with itself, do we?

Comment: You seem badly confused about the definition of an equalizer.  Being an equalizer does not just mean that $gf=hf$; it additionally means $f$ has a certain universal property.

Comment: Oh right, my bad, I forgot anything else with the relevant property must factor through it uniquely! That answers the first question, thanks! Still, the second question holds: why don't we require non-surjectivity?

Comment: Why would you require it?  What's wrong with equalizing an arrow with itself?

Comment: Then any arrow would be an equalizer for some other arrow (if there is one), which seems a too degenerate case that doesn't shed any light on the arrow itself. But, again, my question then was rather about whether this is commonly accepted, and looks like it is!

Comment: No, only injective maps are equalizers.  Remember, you still need the universal property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Only monomorphisms are pullbacks of the $\top:1\to\Omega$ arrow. Suppose that $m:M\to B$ is a monomorphism classified by $\chi$; if $\chi\circ f:A\to B\to \Omega$ is equal to $\top\circ !_A$, then it's the fact that $m$ is a pullback of $\top$ along $\chi$ that gives us the unique arrow $e:A\to M$ with $m\circ e=f$. And this is precisely what makes $m$ an equalizer of $\chi$ and $\top\circ !_B$.
2. No, of course not. Why exclude the trivial case when doing so buys us nothing and complicates the definition?